# AWS Lambda -- Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a python script I'm trying to run via Lambda.

I made a copy of my py script, renamed it `lambda_function.py`
I simply nested the code inside a function `def lambda_handler(event, context):`  (unsure if that's all that you need to do there?)

I then made a new folder .. `lambdatest` and inside of it at the root, i put both the lambda_function.py file and a `packages` folder that is a copy of my `venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages` folder

I upload to Lambda via s3 (as its 55mb slightly over the 50mb straight upload limit)
When I test in lambda it gives the error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I have read through many of the same threads online but I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong :(

Comment: What is the structure of your zip?

Comment: @Marcin a python script lambda_function.py and then 1 subfolder for packages that is a copy paste of my venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages folder of the project

Comment: So you have `lambdatest` folder in your zip? also lambda does not support p3.9, so even if you make the zip work, you may have further issues.

Comment: no my zip file is called `lambdatest`

Comment: To leverage python packages, those should be part of parent directory. Your lambda_function.py can be in nested directory but make sure relative path is correctly mentioned in Handler. Download & extract zip file and check if all site packages are parent directory and also lambda_function.py you are referring is correctly mentioned in Handler. Lemme know if you need an example structure.

Comment: @Ash But nothing is nested? The zip is called lambdatest.zip directly inside that is the lambda_function.py and a 'packages' folder that has all the libraries needed.

Comment: @stubbsy, libraries should be in parent folder and not in child folder ('packages'). Ex: You have pandas library referred in lamba_function.py. Then your zip file structure would look like pandas(library directory) + lambda_function.py.  In a nutshell, all libraries and lambda function should be in top level directory.